# Is it feasible to use Func<T, TResult> or Action<T> to achieve this?

Tags: c#, delegates, func

Working on reorganizing my unit tests, I'm currently looking at different possibilities to achieve this:

#### CustomerTests

```
[TestClass]
public class CustomerTests : SuperTestBaseClass {
    public CustomerTests() : base() { }

    [TestMethod]
    public void NameThrowsWhenNull() { 
        Throws<ArgumentNullException>(customer.Name = null);
    }
}
```

#### SuperTestBaseClass

```
public abstract class SuperTestBaseClass {
    protected SuperTestBaseClass() { }

    public void Throws<TException>(Func<T, TResult> propertyOrMethod) {
        // arrange
        Type expected = typeof(TException);
        Exception actual = null;

        // act
        try { propertyOrMethod(); } catch (Exception ex) { actual = ex; }

        // assert
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, expected);
    }
}
```

Where the `propertyOrMethod` would get executed there in the `try/catch`, without having to write something like:

```
try { propertyOrMethod.Name = null } catch...
```

Since the goal is to make this method the most generic possible to promote code reuse.

It is feasible? If yes, then how?

Comment: Use [`[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx) on your method, and you won't need any custom stuff.

Comment: Your code will work, but remember that you can't call a Property, so the naming is a little off. Additionally, you aren't currently passing it a valid Func<T, TResult> from what I can tell. Do you need help forming the lambda?

Comment: @LordTakkera: Definitely! I need help to form the lambda.

Comment: A Func<T, TResult> would look like: (a) => return (a == somevalue); This is obviously a generic example since I don't know what T or TResult is, but you need to accept an argument (the (a)) and return a TResult.

Comment: @LordTakkera: I have read on MSDN the difference between an Action<T> and a Func<T, TResult>. I'm not used to work with generic delegates. I'm starting with this `SuperTestBaseClass` example to give it a context to live in so trying to make a concrete example of its purpose for my own use and experiment. Then, once I have grasp the jist of it, I shall push it further and do some researh and analysis to see how I can generalize things using BDD, DDD, TDD and Clean Code.

Comment: @LordTakkera: I had not thought of it this way. I shall try an example with the `Throws<TException>`, one that will return the thrown exception, and another that will handle it from within, to work the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
public TException Throws<TException>(Action act) where TException : Exception 
{
        // act
        try { act(); } catch (TException ex) { return ex; }

        // assert
        Assert.Fail("Expected exception");
        return default(TException);   //never reached
}
```

Then you can do

```
Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => { customer.Name = null; });
```

Note that NUnit has this method built in (`Assert.Throws/Catch`) so you don't need this if you're using that.

Comment: Why would you need to do that, instead of using build in attribute?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - The attribute covers the entire test method while this only covers a single statement.

Comment: @Lee If you can’t add the attribute because the method tests multiple things, then it’s no longer a **unit** test and you should split the test up.

Comment: @poke You bit me to that one. If you need to ensure that just one line throws an exception, your test already tests to many things and should be split into two.

Comment: @poke - No I don't think so, your setup could accidentaly throw and cause the test to pass erroneously. More local assertions are preferable, and you also get to examine the exception using this method.

Comment: +1 I shall try this. I have never thought of doing it this way. I know about NUnit, and thanks for highlighting it. I know there are multiple ways of doing stuff, and am aware that we/I overpush once in a while. Aside, I am also investigating to bring my knowledge further and further, so I am looking for different ways to decouple mest tests and promote code reuse, without handcuffing myself with a single unit test framework. I use this as part of my investigation for a proper code organization and am always striving to improve over and over again. It feel overwhelmed sometimes. =)

Comment: @Lee If that’s really your concern, and your setup methods are that complicated, then you should really think about unit testing your unit tests…

Comment: @Lee: How would you make it work as a strongly type method, that is, if I want to write something similar to: `Throws<ArgumentNullException, Customer>(c => { c.Name = null; });`?

Comment: @WillMarcouiller Add second type parameter: `public TException Throws <TException, TItem>(Action<TItem> act) where TException : Exception`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx) on your method, and you won't need any custom stuff.

```
[TestClass]
public class CustomerTests : SuperTestBaseClass {
    public CustomerTests() : base() { }

    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException)]
    public void NameThrowsWhenNull() { 
        customer.Name = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 As I see it fits my above example. I didn't know about this attribute. What I dislike though is that it strongly couple my tests to one framework. Using a kind of `SuperTestBaseClass` with generalized tests like the above, I may change of unit testing framework on a day to day basis. Of course, that is not what I plan on doing, but believe I would benefit from using the lambda expression approach, be it for some other foreign purposes. Aside, it doesn't seem to respect the `// arrange // act // assert` format. I'm perhaps overevangelizing here...

Answer (score 1):

If you use NUnit then you can do this:

`Assert.That(() => { ... }, Throws.InstanceOf<ArgumentException>()));`

You can substitute the lambda expression for a delegate instance if you need to.

Comment: +1 I had never thought of using other assertions than `Assert.AreEqual`, `Assert.IsTrue/False`, `Assert.IsInstanceOfType`...

Comment: I like `Assert.That` because I like NUnit's method chaining syntax. I find it very intuitive.